# How to migrate models from a models package hierarchy and not from models.py with SOUTH in Django?

Tags: django, migration, django-south

Hy!

I have my models in a hierarchy below "models" package:

```
 models
 |-a.py
 |-b.py
```

instead of having all my models into the models.py

But when I run the migration command for South it doesn't find any of them:

```
schemamigration my_app --auto
```

In the meta class already exists the app_label='my_app'

I use auto because the tables are already changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you imported all the models in `__init__.py`? If you've done that, there's effectively no difference in how it works.