# Django South: How can I access models in sub-packages in migrations

Tags: python, django, django-south, data-migration

Since our app has many models, we place them in sub-packages of the models packages, i.e. the `Cheddar`model would not be in `models.Cheddar`, but instead in `models.cheese.Cheddar`.

It seems I cannot access these models in a South datamigration, even though I created an `models/__init__.py` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8123602/54547) containing the line `from cheese import *`.

In my data migration file, the line `for cheddar in orm.Cheddar.objects.all():` still causes the following error:

```
AttributeError: The model 'Cheddar' from the app 'core' is not available in this migration. (Did you use orm.ModelName, not orm['app.ModelName']?)
```

Trying to use `orm['core.models.cheese.Cheddar']` instead causes this error:

```
KeyError: "The model 'cheddar' from the app 'core' is not available in this migration."
```

Does anyone know how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the problem was in the fact, that the `Cheddar` model was not listed in the `DataMigration` instance's `models`property:

```
class Migration(DataMigration):
    # ...

    models = {
        # ...
    }
```

Once I added the correct model definition in there (which was in the previous migration for me), the data migration worked.